# MongoDB replica set OpLog Gb/Hour increasing rapidly, trying to isolate why

Tags: mongodb

## PROBLEM

MongoDB (v 2.6.6) three node replica set OpLog Gb/Hour increasing rapidly over the course of several days having been at 20mb per hour for months. I am attempting to isolate why. In understand Oplog.rs is a Capped Collection and this is related to increase transaction volumes but I finding it difficult to isolate the cause of the increase transaction volumes.

> OPLOG Gb/HOUR
>
> April 2nd - 11th = 20mb per hour.
>
> April 12th - 13th = 40mb per hour.
>
> April 14th - 18th = 50mb per hour.
>
> April 19th = 70mb per hour.
>
> April 20th = 120mb per hour.
>
> April 21st = 180mb per hour.
>
> April 22nd = 230mb per hour.
>
> April 23rd = 310mb per hour.
>
> April 24th = 650mb per hour.

## DEBUGGING TO DATE

- Executed db.getProfilingStatus() on all Databases. All databases returned:

  ```
  {
  "was" : 0,
  "slowms" : 100
  }
  ```

  "0" being profiler disabled.
- Confirmed the growth is not an equivalent increase in client numbers.
- Querying the collection oplog.rs so far have not presented any obvious paterns. Development team confirmed increased persistence of data was not expected following an update on the 16th. I have not ruled out a bug but no obvious exceptions are visible at this time.
- Avg Obj Size in DB.local (which contains the oplog.rs collection) shows a similar growth pattern to Oplog GB/hour.  Was 7.45Kb for a long time. Is now 50KB. Not sure if this is cause or effect.

Looking for further tips/tricks that may help this isolation process if possible please.

Replication OpLog Window dropped from 5300hrs 22nd Feb to 73hrs today.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please ask any questions which are about administration of MongoDB and not about development on https://dba.stackexchange.com. I nominated your question for migration.

Comment: Thank you Philipp, sorry about that. MongoDB website appeared to direct me here. Thank you for migration request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query local.oplog.rs, to see what is in the oplog.

I'd check for documents above the average object size in oplog to see how it is used.

Something like:

```
db['oplog.rs'].find()
    .limit(50)
    .forEach(
        function (x) { 
            if(Object.bsonsize(x) > 70000) 
                print(x);
        }
    );
```

Better start with smaller limit, so that you do not get several megabytes on first query.

My blind guess is you have some growing documents which get queried and updated as a whole.

Comment: Thank you for the post Fox. 
BSON size set to 50000.
Limit set to 1000.
24 objects returned.
Looking at results now.

Comment: Your query helped isolate clients with large JSON payloads thank you. We can see these clients are operating out with what we would consider normal operations. The payload is written to a collection multiple times and cached in a collection per object on an overwrite basis. The Oplog obviously has to log all of these transactions. In the case whereby the payload is exceptional the Oplog data growth is compounded because of the cache collections writes. Changes have been applied, awaiting results.

Comment: Oplog /Gb hour dropping.
Replication Oplog Window increasing.
Ave Object size in oplog.cs collection dropping.
Idetified and resolved.
Thank you , marked as answered. Have a nice day. Scott